# C++ WinSock: Sending large integer values (long long) over UDP

Tags: c++, udp, timestamp, winsock, long-integer

I'm attempting to include a timestamp in my UDP packets sent through winsock. For this I'm sending the duration of a std::chrono::time_point as a long long. Here is the struct that is being sent:

```
struct PlayMessage
{ // Signals that both players are connected and should begin the game
    MessageType type;

    // Time used to synchronised applications ideas of time
    long long syncTime;

    PlayMessage()
        : type(MT_PLAY)
    {
    }
};
```

And this is how I create the message:

```
long long sync = the_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();

    while (message1 == false)
    {
        // Create play message
        PlayMessage play;
        play.type = MT_PLAY;
        play.syncTime = sync; // Set current clock time as authoritative time accross applications

        // Send replies
        int sendcount = sendto(sock, (const char *)&play, sizeof(PlayMessage),
            0, (const sockaddr *)&player1Addr, sizeof(player1Addr));
        if (sendcount == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            die("Sending play to client returned error");
        }
        else if (sendcount != sizeof(PlayMessage))
        {
            die("Whole message was not sent");
        }
        else
        {
            // Sent
            message1 = true;
        }
    }
```

At this point, when setting a break point at the sendto function, the message contains the correct value for the timestamp:

```
syncTime    14809661934978444   __int64
```

EDIT: Oops, here's the receive code client-side!

```
// Wait for one of the sockets to become readable
        int selcount = select(0, &readable, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
        if (selcount == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            Break("select failed");
        }
        if (FD_ISSET(sock, &readable))
        {
            int reccount = recv(sock, playBuffer, sizeof(PlayMessage), 0);
            if (reccount < 0)
            {
                int error = WSAGetLastError();
                Break("recvfrom failed");
            }
            if (reccount != sizeof(PlayMessage))
            {
                Break("received odd-sized message");
            }
        }

        PlayMessage recvd;
        memcpy(&recvd, playBuffer, sizeof(PlayMessage));

        // Check message type
        if (recvd.type != MT_PLAY)
        {
            // Not a player request, continue with loop
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            // Play
            play = true;

            // Store data into new struct
            PlayMessage recvd;
            memcpy(&recvd, echoBuffer, sizeof(PlayMessage));

            // Store server-authoritative time 
            long long duration = recvd.syncTime + duration_cast<milliseconds>(latency / 2).count();
            start = the_clock::time_point(milliseconds(duration));

            // Now all three applications have a *similar* idea of the current time
        }
```

On the client side, when reading the message, everything is zeroed (including the message type.)

```
-       recvd   {type=MT_UNKNOWN (0) syncTime=0 }   PlayMessage
                type      MT_UNKNOWN (0)    MessageType
                syncTime       0            __int64
```

Is this perhaps because of the size of the integer being sent? I'm wary the packet may be too large when sent, or perhaps the select function is timing out on the client side before it is read entirely? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You didn't show us the receive code! Also, this is a *terrible* design. You should start by documenting the protocol (at the datagram and byte levels) the program will use and then implementing the protocol you documented. You should *not* start with code. For one thing, if you start with code, it's literally impossible to know if the code above is correct, because we have no specification to test its compliance with. Does this send the type the way the receiver expects? How can we know?

Comment: Added receive code David

Comment: Your provided code can't possibly produce the provided output. So we still can't tell where the issue is. Did you add logging after the first `memcpy` in the receive code?

Comment: Also, two issues: 1) You monkey with the receive buffer even if the `if (FD_ISSET(...` code doesn't run. 2) Your code assumes that both sender and receiver will layout `PlayMessage` exactly the same way. This is likely if they're the same OS, same compiler, and so on. But likely to fail if they're not.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Hi David, thanks for your feedback, I'm very new to network programming so outlining and implementing a very detailed protocol as you describe is a bit daunting. Clearly it is far more critical than I first thought.

Comment: You may want to consider using text at first. It's much simpler. Alternatively, consider using some kind of serialization library.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I've also realised that I'm memcpy'ing twice which is totally overwriting what comes in from the socket. This is the result of a long day in front of the screen. Thanks for your help, I'll look into a serialization library to get the packets more predictable.